# What is the source of slow response time on client when server is fast, in Python web app hosted in Azure

Tags: django, performance, azure, django-rest-framework

I have a simple Python web app hosted in Azure. Here are the details:

- Azure App Service for Linux (Basic Service Plan - B1 with 1 core)
- Django framework
- Postgres backend via Azure Databases for PostgreSQL
- Uses Vue on the client-side
- All services are located in the same resource group

**Problem**

It is a simple app and the database **queries take about 30ms**, including the time to fetch. However, the app is performing quite slowly.The initial load time of the SPA in the client is around **10s**, with subsequent requests taking around **7-8s**.

**Troubleshooting**

I took a look at the response times in application insights and it seemed acceptable to me.

[image: Response time of request]

I then took a look at the requests for a single page load. I noticed that while the individual responses for each API call were fast, there one about 1s between each request.

[image: Request for a single page load]

I then tried various gunicorn configurations, changing the workers & threads. I settled on **1 worker with 4 threads**. This improved performance to **1.5-2s per page load** after the SPA loads. This is still not quite satisfactory, especially considering that **applications insights** suggests that the **median response time is 160ms**.

I then scaled the app all the way up to the premium service plan **(P3v2 with 4 cores), using 1 worker and 9 threads in the gunicorn** configuration and the response on the client is the same. Any suggestions on what could be going on?

Comment: Are you hosting the application close to your customers? E.g customer is in Europe, and you're hosting in US. This time can be a latency problem...

Comment: Yes, our customers (and even developers) are in the same region as the Azure data center.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio we were wondering if it is possible if it is an Azure specific issue, as we develop these types of small apps all the time in GCP and have never had a problem. We have so much as not even had to play around with the gunicorn configuration.

Comment: If you, your developers are getting the results from the print screen, it's clear that it's something on the client side. Ask them to use a different network and compare the results

Comment: We have tried on different networks already and the results are the same.

Comment: This is really a big issue with Django and Azure web app service, I wish we get a quicker solution